# Issues in linking Files between Projects in a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have solution with 3 projects. 
[image]

SharingFilesTest have a file MainPage.xaml and the other two projects have this MainPage.xaml added as a link.
So, the issue is when I try to use any App.xaml.cs GLOBAL variable in MainPage.xaml.cs file it says "The name 'App' doesnot exist." only when I tried to Build Pro1 and Pro2. SharingFilesTest works fine
[image]

However, I have defined the same variable in all App.xaml.cs in the solution. I mean Pro1, Pro2 and SharingFilesTest all three have the same variable.

I haved tried referencing Pro1 and Pro2 in SharingFilesTest and then add Using statement for both Pro1 and Pro2. But still doesnt work as Pro1 doenst know Pro2 and vice versa.

Comment: It happens because they are in different namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually better to share a view among multiple assemblies by moving that code into a separate class library that all your other assemblies can then reference.  Linking the code file itself, as you've done in this case, is definitely not the preferred method.

That said... if you're determined to just link the exact code file, you'll need to move your global variable into a class which exists in the same namespace within each project.  Your projects should therefore not reference each others' assemblies.

For example, you might add a file called Globals.cs which uses the same namespace in each project:

```
namespace SharedNS
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public const int MyGlobalVar = 0;
    }
}
```

The App.xaml.cs files, which should probably stay in the project-specific namespaces (e.g. Pro1, Pro2, SharingFilesTest) can reference the Globals object if needed.

Comment: yes...i understand. but still i cant reference Globals in App.xaml.cs

Comment: You'll need to use the fully-qualified name to reference it, e.g. SharedNS.Globals.MyGlobalVar

Comment: okay...i think i am too confused now......how to reference the Globals.MyGlobalVar in MainPage.xaml.cs (which is linked file)

Comment: You will need to include the namespace when referencing the class; that's what "fully-qualified" means.  As long as you have a separate Globals.cs file in each project then that will work.  If you want Globals to be shared among your projects also then you really ought to just use a shared assembly and skip the file linking.

Comment: when i use like this in MainPage.xaml.cs int anyNum = Pro2.Globals.MyGlobalVar then Pro2 is not found in other two projects.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the namespace Pro2.  It should be in the same namespace in all your projects e.g. SharedNS in my example above.